# Audio output balancing problem

Tags: audio-jack

My left speaker doesn't work. So i want to use only my right speaker in my laptop. How to configure it. I am using kubuntu 17.04. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the left make NO sound or BAD sound? Big difference. It it is NO sound, just set system to play audio as mono.

Comment: it makes BAD sound. I want to balance the output to only right.

Comment: Do you have the Volume Control gui? If you do, go to Output Devices and click the lock icon, That should lock/unlock the channels.

Comment: And set it to mono anyway, come to think of it. Since you'll be essentially turning the left off, you want both channels sent to the right. As to exactly how - noticing the tag you put on this - I use a different setup - so I don't know jack. ;-)

Comment: hello WillemK, thanks for your help. Can you tell me how to install Volume Control gui and  procedure to lock/unlock the control